# Why does this cause a memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

Say I have an `AbstractBaseClass` and a `ConcreteSubclass`.

The following code creates the ConcreteSubclass and then disposes of it perfectly fine and without memory leaks:

```
ConcreteSubclass *test = new ConcreteSubclass(args...);
delete test;
```

However, as soon as I push this pointer into a vector, I get a memory leak:

```
std::vector<AbstractBaseClass*> arr;
arr.push_back(new ConcreteSubclass(args...));
delete arr[0];
```

I get fewer memory leaks with `delete arr[0];` than with no delete at all, but still some memory gets leaked.

I did plenty of looking online and this seems to be a well understood problem - I'm deleting the pointer to the memory but not the actual memory itself. So I tried a basic dereference... `delete *arr[0];` but that just gives a compiler error. I also tried a whole load of other references and dereferences but each just gives either a compiler error or program crash. I'm just not hitting on the right solution.

Now, I can use a `shared_ptr` to get the job done without a leak just fine (Boost as I don't have C++11 available to me):

```
std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<AbstractBaseClass>> arr2;
arr2.push_back(boost::shared_ptr<AbstractBaseClass>(new ConcreteSubclass(args...)));
```

but I can't get the manual method to work. It's not really important - it's perfectly easy to just use Boost, but I really want to know what I'm doing wrong so I can learn from it rather than just move without finding out my error.

I tried tracing through Boost's shared_ptr templates, but I keep getting lost because each function has so many overloads and I'm finding it very difficult to follow which branch to take each time.

I think it's this one:

```
template<class Y>
explicit shared_ptr( Y * p ): px( p ), pn() // Y must be complete
{
    boost::detail::sp_pointer_construct( this, p, pn );
}
```

But I keep ending up at `checked_array_delete`, but that can't be right as that uses `delete[]`. I need to get down to just

```
template<class T> inline void checked_delete(T * x)
{
    // intentionally complex - simplification causes regressions
    typedef char type_must_be_complete[ sizeof(T)? 1: -1 ];
    (void) sizeof(type_must_be_complete);
    delete x;
}
```

And that's just calling `delete`, nothing special. Trying to follow through all of the reference and dereference operators was a disaster from the start. So basically I'm stuck, and I couldn't figure out how Boost made it work whilst my code didn't. So back to the start, how can I re-write this code to make the delete not leak?

```
std::vector<AbstractBaseClass*> arr;
arr.push_back(new ConcreteSubclass(args...));
delete arr[0];
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is the destructor of `AbstractBaseClass` virtual?

Comment: Also, if you are not familiar with the need for virtual destructors in C++, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/461224/131407.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shared_ptr` stores a "deleter", a helper function<sup>1</sup> that casts the pointer back to its original type (`ConcreteSubclass*`) before calling `delete`.  You haven't done this.

If `AbstractBaseClass` has a virtual destructor, then calling `delete arr[0];` is fine and works just as well as `delete (ConcreteSubclass*)arr[0];`.  If it doesn't, then deletion through a base subobject is undefined behavior, and can cause far worse things to happen than memory leaks.

Rule of thumb: **Every abstract base class should have a user-declared (explicitly defaulted is ok) destructor that is**

- `virtual`

OR

- modified by `protected:` accessibility

or both.

---

<sup>1</sup> You've found the implementation, it is `checked_delete`.  But it is instantiated with the return type from `new` -- `checked_delete<ConcreteSubclass>(ConcreteSubclass* x)`.  So it is using ordinary delete, but on a pointer to type `ConcreteSubclass`, and that makes it possible for the compiler to find the right destructor even without the help of virtual dispatch.

Comment: Thanks for explaining how `shared_ptr` invokes the correct dtor!

Comment: Ah! I understand what's going on now & it's working great. Thank you to everyone here who helped. This is actually my first project in OOP - as you've worked out, I'm still very new. Anyway, thanks again everyone. I'll mark this as the answer in a couple of minutes.